# Excel sheet size reduced on resaving

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter, libreoffice-calc

I created an excel sheet with python xlsxwriter. When i resaved it with libreoffice calc the size decreased by more than 60 percent. why is it ? Is there any way i can mimic this in python to reduce my file size?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that also happens with files produced by Excel so it isn’t an issue with XlsxWriter files. You can verify this by saving the file in Excel and then LibreOffice to test the change.

XlsxWriter files should be the same size (with small percentage differences) as Excel files since the XML part is almost exactly the same. The zip compression may differ though.

Answer (score 0):

The size sometimes reduces if you have empty cells on the list. Similar behavior is when you move in Excel to cell A1 and then save, the file size decreases. But you generated the file, so this behaviour may not necessarily apply.